# Is there a way to group Kendo UI scheduler resources by type?

Tags: kendo-ui, resources, grouping, scheduler

I'm using the scheduler to show hotel rooms booking so I used the resources attribute as described in the [documentation](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/resources) .. so far everything went good.

Now I need to extend what I have and include **room types** ... something like what's on this [link](https://dojo.telerik.com/OsuLUmod).

Here I'm using **Standard Room** & **strong text** to represent room types and **101**, **102**, **103** as room numbers.

My question is .. is there a way to make every **room type** have its own **distinct** room numbers instead of repeating the same set of room numbers in every room type?

In scheduler terms ... Can I group resources by something other than orientation/date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource grouping in the manner of a hierarchical data source is not yet a feature of the Scheduler component.  The feature is highly requested and can be voted on at https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-jquery-ui/1359266-scheduler-grouping.

The feedback page has a link to Dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/IMelO/7 demonstrating a work around. The work around is based on hiding rows in the `databound` event handler.

> ```
>        dataBound: function(e) {
>         this.view().element.find(".k-scheduler-layout>tbody>tr:nth-child(1)").hide();
>        }
> ```

If you decide to *work around* you will need to create a find selector specific to your data or situation.